# MacOS - can I disable F12, Ctrl-Left Arrow, Ctrl-Right Arrow?

Tags: macos, shortcut

I am using Microsoft Remote Desktop in my MacOS, the Windows is opened in full window so it has its own virtual desktop.

My Windows application heavily uses F12, Ctrl-Left Arrow and Ctrl-Right Arrow. But these shortcuts are associated with Mac to navigate virtual desktops.

Is there a way I can completely disable these keys from being intercepted by Mac?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can disable those keyboard shortcuts:

1. Go to the Apple menu
2. Click System Preferences...
3. Click Keyboard
4. Click the Shortcuts tab
5. Click Mission Control in the left-hand column
6. Uncheck the keyboard shortcuts for Show Dashboard (F12), Move left a space (ctrl-left arrow) and Move right a space (ctrl-right arrow)

Comment: Works like a charm